# Liberty Profile Docker for last version 16.0.0.4 available?

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

anybody has a running Liberty 16.0.0.4 in Docker? Custom Dockerfile?

Last one seems to be officially available (Docker) is 16.0.0.3 but maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The websphere-liberty image on Docker Hub is at the 16.0.0.4 level.

```
$ docker run websphere-liberty:latest productInfo version
Product name: WebSphere Application Server
Product version: 16.0.0.4
Product edition: BASE_ILAN
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I reference it other than :latest, so when websphere-liberty:latest points to 16.0.0.5, I don't have to edit all my docker files to keep it in 16.0.0.4 in case I need that?

Comment: No - we deliberately don't add version tags as a) we want to encourage users to use the latest Liberty fix pack and b) if we did have multiple version tags we would have to continue rebuilding them forever more to ensure that we pick up updates to the base image. I'm not sure whether Docker Hub reaps dangling images. If not, you may be able to use the sha to refer to this image (e.g. docker pull websphere-liberty@sha256:540e62e0dae968bd15ba5f94f62bf9db11baab27c4d03f54fb0d4a58e6878f6a) or just take your own copy. That would, however, mean that you don't get updates even at the 16.0.0.4 level.

Comment: Let me ask you couple of questions related to this. What is the difference between ibmcom/websphere-liberty and web sphere-liberty images? Versions returned are not the same (webProfile7 for example)... .Also... How can I get 16.0.0.4 web profile? websphere-liberty:webProfile7 returns 8.5.5.9 and ibmcom/websphere-liberty:webProfile7 16.0.0.3; thanks!

Comment: The ibmcom images are supposed to be a mirror of the official images (just so that all of the IBM images are available in a single namespace). Thanks for pointing out that the last mirror has obviously failed. I've just corrected that. All of the official images are at the 16.0.0.4 level - I suspect you have a old version cached locally. Try doing another `docker pull`.